# Swift using init in viewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Im trying to configure a few variables only once before the is loaded. i know i can put them in viewWill appear only issue is that I don't want them to happen every time the app is loaded. I tried to use init but maybe I'm doing it incorrectly.

```
//this is my code
 init(){
        //actionBar
        let textFieldInsideSearchBar = searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as! UITextField
        textFieldInsideSearchBar.leftView = profileImg
        textFieldInsideSearchBar.placeholder = ""
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method you are looking for is called viewDidLoad: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621495-viewdidload